# How to make a onFling go from middle to top?

Tags: android, gestures, onfling

I'm making a app where you should be able to swipe over a image from middel to left, middle to right, middle to bottom and middle to top. I have to use gestures. Problem is that I dont know how to make it go from middle to whatever, only from top to bottom.

CODE:

```
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
final ImageView imageView  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arrows);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {
            //onFling();
            return true;
        }
    });
}


    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Opening Microsoft", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.microsoft.com/"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);// Right to left

        }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Opening Roc van Twente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.rocvantwente.nl"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);// Left to right
        }

        if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Opening Apple", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.apple.com"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);// Bottom to top

        }  else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Opening Oracle", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.oracle.com"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);// Top to bottom
        }
        return false;
    }
```